# Prove that this limsup inequality is strict.

Tags: analysis

[image]

so they are non-negative and bounded.
how do i show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that $x_n=1+\sin(n)$, $y_n=1+\cos(n)$ work. The limsup of the product is less than 3. The limsup of each separately is 2, so the product is 4.

Comment: that makes sense. thank you!